# How to put an anchor tag inside an anchor tag

Tags: html, anchor

I have a row, which is inside an anchor tag. Now in that row I want to add another clickable component (an anchor tag). How do I do it?

Comment: You don't. How is the browser meant to know which link to follow? Also, it'd be invalid html.

Answer (score 3):

You don't do it within an anchor.

Anchor elements are not nestable.

The [HTML 4 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) has this:

```
<!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->
```

The `-(A)` means that `A` elements are *explicitly* not allowed within `A` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Why do you want to even put a row inside an anchor tag? If you have multiple links, keep them in seperate anchor tags. If you want to know which anchor link triggered an event give them some id.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
You can simply define one `<div>` element at the top and use anchor tags inside it.
Something like:

```
<div id="myDiv"><a href="#"></a>
     <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

make sure you add click event for myDiv in your script file as well.

`window.location.href = "#dashboardDetails";`

Answer (score -1):

absolutely position the second anchor over the first. whatever your the parent element to a row{} is, set that to position:relative; set a row,a.secondlinkwhatever{position:absolute} then space out the second link where you need it to be and set a z-index on it. without seeing your code, this is pretty vague, but that should work. there are just too many unknown constraints.